# Wrong reinterpretation of the nullptr in a Qt 5.15-based project | C++

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, qt5, nullptr

Both GCC (version 12.2) and Clang (version 14.0) compilers interpret `nullptr` as 32-bit integer (`int`) in some places, and this causes errors.

For example, in the `qhashfunctions.h` file there is a variant of function called `qHash` that takes `nullptr` as a main argument.

```
Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION inline uint qHash(std::nullptr_t, uint seed = 0) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
{
    return qHash(reinterpret_cast<quintptr>(nullptr), seed);
}
```

Any compiler reports that `int` cannot be casted to `quintptr` (`unsigned long long`).

Second example has the same problem. In the `std_thread.h` file there is the following code:

```
_M_start_thread(_State_ptr(new _State_impl<_Wrapper>(
          std::forward<_Callable>(__f), std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)),
        __depend);
      }
```

Earlier in this file `__depend` is declared as `nullptr` (`auto __depend = nullptr;`). This means that function pointer (2nd argument) is `nullptr`. Any compiler reports that a parameter of type `void (*)()` cannot be initialised with a value of type `int`.

What is the solution to the problem?

I use ArchLinux (x86-64) with latest updates and Qt version 5.15.8. Building is done through Qt Creator

I also tried to create another Qt-based project and write the following code in the `main` function:

```
unsigned long long i = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long>(nullptr)
```

Compilation succeded...

Comment: Sounds like your standard library is a bit broken

Comment: Looks like your compiler and stdlib don't match

Comment: It looks like `nullptr` has been defined somewhere (`#define nullptr NULL` or `#define nullptr 0` somewhere) since `auto __depend = nullptr;` gave `__depend` the type `int` (and your error makes sense for `reinterpret_cast<quintptr>(0)`). Try again with `#undef nullptr` and if that works look for the offending define.

Comment: Not sure why you expect `reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long>(nullptr)` to fail, it works on all compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/Me7TPhTWs

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I just tried to understand if that was a problem of the qmake or some Qt-based project default settings

Comment: @Artyer, thank you! Somewhere there is an old chunk of code that defines it. Will take a look for it